# Package gets distributed while importing a project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to import a GUI project into my eclipse kepler on my Windows server 2012. After importing the package explorer looks like:

```
mygui.applet
mygui.swing.main
mygui.swing.main.dialogs
mygui.swing.main.events
```

Where as it should look like:

```
-mygui 
  -mygui.applet
    -mygui.swing
```

Where my gui.swing is the parent package containing dialogs and events.
I tried importing the same project into another eclipse installed on a Windows 8 machine and it gets imported correctly.

Is this a problem of using eclipse on windows server 2012? Are there any pre-requisites I need to be aware of? Which other alternate Java builder can I use alternately on a virtual machine for a project of big size?

The method I am using to import my project is:
Create Java Project-> Import File System->Select Folder (This works on windows 8).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your project. It's a preference in Eclipse. In the top right corner of the Package Explorer view is a downward-pointing triangle which opens up a drop down menu with an option called "Package Presentation" - this opens up a sub menu with the choices of "Flat" or "Hierarchical". You have "Flat" selected and need only to change to "Hierarchical" for the effect you desire.